# Input skeleton not found

Tags: xna, fbx, windows-phone-8

I have a 3D-Model, made in Maya and I am trying to parse that through the latest XNA with the `SkinnedModelProcessor` (However, this issue remains without that processor).

In Maya, the skin is already attached to the skeleton, so why am I getting this error?

> Input skeleton not found

Is there anything special I should think of when exporting that .fbx file from Maya?

Comment: You can get this error in blender if the armatures are not connected. So maybe there is an issue with the way your bones are set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours and hours of debugging we found out that the problem wasn't the skinning or connecting or whatever.

It was the rigging-system.
My designer used a tool called *Advanced Skeleton*, that tool should work perfectly.

However, it doesn't really apply to the XNA-Standards and therefore its rigging-algorithm caused errors in XNA.

We ended up using the standard rigging-tool from Maya. Since then, everything is working.